# How to split string by another string

Tags: c#, regex, edi

I have this string (it's from EDI data):

```
ISA*ESA?ISA*ESA?
```

The `*` indicates it could be any character and can be of any length.

`?` indicates any single character.

Only the `ISA` and `ESA` are guaranteed not to change.

I need this split into two strings which could look like this: `"ISA~this is date~ESA|"` and

```
"ISA~this is more data~ESA|"
```

How do I do this in c#?

I can't use string.split, because it doesn't really have a delimeter.

Comment: EDI is regular and can be parsed with regex.  I however must defer to a regex (and preferably EDI) guru to give you the answer for this one.  I have taken the liberty of adding the regex tag to try to attract some gurus.

Comment: Typically you can read in the delimiters used by an EDI file in the first record, then act accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Regex to split a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156414/using-regex-to-split-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Typically yes.  The issue is that multiple ISA segments are being included in the file, so before the processing is done, the entire file needs to be split into the individual files. The only delimiters are the ISA and ESA segments.

Comment: You can use the [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx) call to split the string using a regex. I don't completely follow what you want it split of, else I could have posted a clearer answer

Comment: Read in the first ISA (should be fixed width) then you'll have the record delimiter, so you search for that delimiter before the next ISA, and you'll have your first break, then repeat if the delimiters can change for each file.  Alternatively you might want to search for existing tools that deal with EDI instead of rolling your own code.

Comment: Maybe [`(?s)ISA(?:(?![IE]SA).)*ESA(?![IE]SA).?`](https://regex101.com/r/rI9ATo/2) is what you need?

Comment: @GregGum: If you need a regex expert help, explain what you need with a clear example (real input text, expected output, why = requirements).

Comment: @Vikhram, your comment is what I ended up using.  If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: just curious: what happens if by change the content contains 'ISA'? Or 'ESA'?

Comment: @juharr, that is exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Split` for accomplishing this

```
string splitStr = "|", inputStr = "ISA~this is date~ESA|ISA~this is more data~ESA|";

var regex = new Regex($@"(?<=ESA){Regex.Escape(splitStr)}(?=ISA)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var items = regex.Split(inputStr);

foreach (var item in items) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output:

```
ISA~this is date~ESA
ISA~this is more data~ESA|
```

Note that if your string between the `ISA` and `ESA` have the same pattern that we are looking for, then you will have to find some smart way around it.

To explain the Regex a bit:

```
(?<=ESA)   Look-behind assertion. This portion is not captured but still matched
(?=ISA)    Look-ahead assertion. This portion is not captured but still matched
```

Using these look-around assertions you can find the correct `|` character for splitting

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the

```
int x = whateverString.indexOf("?ISA"); // replace ? with the actual character here
```

and then just use the substring from 0 to that indexOf, indexOf to length.

Edit:
If ? is not known, 
can we just use the regex Pattern and Matcher.

```
    Matcher matcher = Patter.compile("ISA.*ESA").match(whateverString);
    if(matcher.find()) { 
         matcher.find();
         int x = matcher.start();
    }
```

Here x would  give that start index of that match.

Edit: I mistakenly saw it as java one, for C#

```
  string pattern = @"ISA.*ESA";
  Regex myRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

  Match m = myRegex.Match(whateverString);   // m is the first match
  while (m.Success)
  {
       Console.writeLine(m.value);
       m = m.NextMatch();              // more matches
  }
```

Comment: EDI documents can be huge and have tons of these tags in them that have to be parsed the same way.

Comment: `?` can be any character, so you don't know what the actual character is.

Comment: Your edit turned my downvote into an upvote.  This right here should give the OP enough to start with.

Answer (score 1):

RegEx will probably be the best for this. See [this link](https://regex101.com/r/uRVC0h/1/)

Mask would be

```
ISA(?<data1>.*?)ESA.ISA(?<data2>.*?)ESA.
```

This will give you 2 groups with data you need

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"ISA(?<data1>.*?)ESA.ISA(?<data2>.*?)ESA.",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    var data1 = match.Groups["data1"].Value;
    var data2 = match.Groups["data2"].Value;
}
```

Use `Regex.Matches` If you need multiple matches found, and specify different `RegexOptions` if needed.

Comment: To explain: .*? means match 0 or more (*) arbitrary characters (.) in a non-greedy manner (?), i.e. stop at the first occurrence the next pattern (here ESA) matches. If you know that between ISA and ESA there is always at least one character you can substitute * by +. The expression (?<x>y) labels the pattern y with the name x.

Comment: If you follow link I gave at the top of the answer, you will see full explanation of Regex on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regex like ISA(.+?)ESA and select the first group

```
string input = "ISA~mycontent+ESA";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"ISA(.+?)ESA",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
   string key = match.Groups[1].Value;              
}
```

Comment: Can you add a short example in C# of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hacky but you could do...

```
string x = "ISA*ESA?ISA*ESA?";

x = x.Replace("*","~"); // OR SOME OTHER DELIMITER

string[] y = x.Split('~');
```

Not perfect in all situations, but it could solve your problem simply.

Comment: I read "hacky" as a suggestion for pre-processing the data, which isn't a terrible suggestion, pre-processing to simplify the main algorithm.

Comment: Except the question was misunderstood. The * and ? are not literal characters

Comment: @JesperNiedermann why? It works if you replace the * with any string of any length, so what's the problem?

Comment: @MetaColon because the string does not contain a *. The *  "indicates it could be any character of any length"

Comment: @JesperNiedermann as I said it would work if the * was a string of any length as well?!

Comment: @MetaColon only true if the string was known ahead of time. Well I suppose you could read the question like that if you want to be very literal about it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could split by "ISA" and "ESA" and then put the parts back together.

> string input = "ISA~this is date~ESA|ISA~this is more data~ESA|";

```
string start = "ISA",
    end = "ESA";
var splitedInput = input.Split(new[] { start, end }, StringSplitOptions.None);

var firstPart = $"{start}{splitedInput[1]}{end}{splitedInput[2]}";
var secondPart = $"{start}{splitedInput[3]}{end}{splitedInput[4]}";
```

> firstPart = "ISA~this is date~ESA|"
>
> secondPart = "ISA~this is more data~ESA|";

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "splitting" by a string, I would instead describe your question as "grouping" by a string. This can easily be done using a regular expression:

---

Regular expression: `^(ISA.*?(?=ESA)ESA.)(ISA.*?(?=ESA)ESA.)$`

Explanation:

- `^` - asserts position at start of the string

  - `(` - start capturing group
  - `ISA` - match string `ISA` exactly
  - `.*?(?=ESA)` - match any character 0 or more times, positive lookahead on the 
    string `ESA` (basically match any character until the string `ESA` is found)
  - `ESA` - match string `ESA` exactly
  - `.` - match any character
  - `)` - end capturing group
  - repeat one more time...
- `$` - asserts position at end of the string

[Try it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uZYu1w/1)

---

Example:

```
string input = "ISA~this is date~ESA|ISA~this is more data~ESA|";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(ISA.*?(?=ESA)ESA.)(ISA.*?(?=ESA)ESA.)$",
    RegexOptions.Compiled);

Match match = regex.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
{
    string firstValue  = match.Groups[1].Value; // "ISA~this is date~ESA|"
    string secondValue = match.Groups[2].Value; // "ISA~this is more data~ESA|"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to the question "How to split a string by another string".

```
var matches = input.Split(new [] { "ISA" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and

```
var matches = Regex.Split(input, "ISA").ToList();
```

However, the first removes empty entries, while the second does not.

Comment: Honestly, this is a bad solution that just happens to work. What if your pattern is `ISA*ESA?ESA*ISA?`? How would you "split" this?

Comment: In my case, the pattern is will never change.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245442/c-sharp-split-a-string-by-another-string

Comment: @budi, Good link, I added that to my answer