# Delete the comma from the string when comma and parenthesis exists in field without considering comma within the parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression in C# csv that can contain:
code as

```
a,a,(a,b,(a)).
```

I have tried the following:

```
var result = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(input, @"([^,()]+(\([^()]*\))?") select m.Value).ToArray();
string result1 = ConvertStringArrayToString(result);
textBox2.Text = result1;
```

but i get output like this:

```
a
a
a
b(a)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a comma delimited string when comma and parenthesis exists in field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477767/how-to-parse-a-comma-delimited-string-when-comma-and-parenthesis-exists-in-field)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732029/how-to-split-string-by-unless-is-within-brackets-using-regex for an alternative solution.

Comment: a,b(aa,bb,c) ,a  its the input string .

Comment: expected output is a b(aa,bb,c)   a

Answer (score 0):

You need [balancing group definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#balancing_group_definition) to make it work:

```
[^,()]*(?:\(([^()]*|(?<open>\()|(?<-open>\)))*(?(open)(?!))\))*[^,()]*
```

[DEMO](http://goo.gl/99pAXw)

A good introduction into BGD is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/2729609) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13425789/2729609)